# How remove line space from file python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file like this.

```
Girl: I am girl.

Boy:

I am boy
```

I am using this code to remove line space.

```
import string
from itertools import ifilter, imap
print '\n'.join(ifilter(None, imap(string.strip, open('doc1.txt'))))
```

Using this it is giving me this output.

```
Girl: I am girl.
Boy:
I am boy
```

It is not removing space between `Boy:` and `I am boy`. How I can remove that line space? I want output in this format.

```
Girl: I am girl.
Boy:  I am boy.
```

Comment: Can you show how the output should look like?

Comment: Iterate over the file; check if each line is empty (newline only); if not empty save the line; if empty skip the line.

Comment: @Akshay : Included my desired output in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex should get close. Unfortunately, has to read the whole file content to a string.

```
import re

test_str = '''Girl: I am girl.

Boy:

I am boy

Dog: Bark

Cat: 

Meow'''

regex = r':\s*\n+'
subst = ": "

for line in re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE).split('\n'):
    if line != '':
        print (line.strip())
```

Output

```
Girl: I am girl.
Boy: I am boy
Dog: Bark
Cat: Meow
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, and just print those lines that aren't empty.

```
with open('test', 'r') as fd:
    for l in fd:
        if l != '\n':
            print(l.strip())
```

Comment: I don't think this puts `Boy: I am boy`, which is what the question wants

Comment: You don't have to call ```readlines()``` - a file object is an iterator that returns lines. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: @cricket_007 : yes you are right. I have included my desired output in my question.